# How to set which tabPanel to show when launching a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

When I run the app, I want the `tab 2` to be clicked, so I can see it first, not `tab 1`. How can I do so ?

```r
# USER INTERFACE 
ui <-  fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("tab 1"),
      tabPanel("tab 2"),
    )
  )
)
# SERVER 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Use the `selected`  parameter of the `tabSetPanel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
tabSetPanel(tabPanel("tab1"), tabPanel("tab2"), selected="tab2")
```